# How Concatenate 2 Java Map<String, Object> with same keys without override

Tags: java, dictionary

How Concatenate 2 Java `Map<String, Object>` with same keys without override

Hi, I'm trying to concatenate 2 maps in java, and try with `putAll()` but this method override values with same key

Example initial maps:

```
{Foo: "A", Bar: "B"}
{Foo: "C", Bar: "D"}
```

I want some like this:

```
{ Foo0: "A", Bar0: "B", Foo1: "C", Bar1: "D" }
```

Comment: build a method to manually check if a key is there before adding it?

Comment: I suggest you create the new keys as you add them.

Comment: It's unclear what your rules are for the keys in the resulting map.  Do you want to modify *all* the keys of the original maps, or only those that collide?  Either way, how do you anticipate that users of the new map will know which keys to use?

Comment: Assuming you want to modify *all* keys, it's still unclear whether you want non-colliding keys to start at the "0" suffix, or use a common suffix for all keys in a map. My answer assumes the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you considering the following structure: `Map<String, List<String>>`.

In that case, you needn't override a key, just put a value to the end of the list by this key. Also, you don't have to think about how to name new keys (`Bar0`, `Bar1`). Finally, if a new map appears (third, fourth), its values will be added without issues.

Some pseudo-code for you:

```
map.put(key, 
        map.get(key) == null ? newListAddValueReturnList :
                               getListAddValueReturnList);
```

Well, the code also is written for you:

```
String v = map.get(key);

if(v == null)
    map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>() {{ add(value); }});
else
    v.add(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what your requirements are, as @JohnBollinger pointed out. But if we take your example very simplistically, you just want to append an index to the end of each key, in which case you can do something like this:

```
static Map<String, Object> merge(Map<String, Object> map1, Map<String, Object> map2) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    map1.forEach((k, v) -> result.put(k + "0", v));
    map2.forEach((k, v) -> result.put(k + "1", v));
    return result;
}
```